# How do we put related models fields Unique together ?

Tags: django

i have model i want related vendor and product to be unique together .

```
class Vendoroffer(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor) 
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product )
    cost_price = models.DecimalField( max_digits=15 , decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Model.validate_unique method you might achieve what u want.

```
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    qs = Vendoroffer.objects.filter(vendor=self.vendor)
    if qs.filter(product = self.product).exists():
        raise ValidationError('Error Message Here')
```

Refere Django Documentation for More:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects